# How RaiseEvent Event Functions Just In One Place in Yii Framework CComponent

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii-events

as You know for making System Event Based You Should create Event Functions for Each of them so this is sample:

in Controller which Extended CComponents i create function:

```
public function onDashboardInit($event)
    {
    $this->raiseEvent('onDashboardInit',$event);
    }
public function onAfterLoginForm($event)
        {
                $this->raiseEvent('onAfterLoginForm',$event);
        }
```

, ...............................
so You see for each event we should create function and it makes extra code, so i need a way to remove this extra code
may be editing CComponent Magic function is Solution , but how?

Second Question:
2- is this logical to add all those events functions in Controller Class (this Class extends CController) to make Events System Wide So i Can Access All Events Even in Components and Extensions????
is there better way to make Controller Lighter for Proccessing and remove overloading due to lines of code